# Error on the second fragment with recycler view layout manager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I have a mainActivity with a fragment container which i set one of three fragments in it.
In each one i have a recycler view and I move to the next fragment on an item click.
The first fragment with the recyclerView is set as follows

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_courses, container, false);

    mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mCoursesList = view.findViewById(R.id.courses_rv);

    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    mCoursesList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    mCoursesList.setHasFixedSize(true);

    updateView();

    return view;
}
```

the error happens when entering the second fragment which is done as

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_subjects, container, false);

    mSubjectsList = view.findViewById(R.id.subjects_rv);

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    mSubjectsList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mSubjectsList.setHasFixedSize(true);

    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        courseName = bundle.getString( "CourseName");
        subjectName = bundle.getString( "SubjectName");
    }

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;
}
```

Apparently they are the same but with the error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
```

The XML files 
Main2Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.crash.mathtest.Views.Main2Activity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    ></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

CoureseFragment:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.crash.mathtest.Views.CoursesFragment">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/courses_rv"
    />
 </FrameLayout>
```

Subjects fragment is the same as courses fragment

Again, this only appears on the second fragment (onCreateView)
The error points to the setLayoutManager(linearLayout)

Can't I make new layouts in the same activity ? 
doesn't the new one override the last ?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
do this stuff in 
onActivityCreated from onCreateView

```
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
mSubjectsList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
mSubjectsList.setHasFixedSize(true);

Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
    courseName = bundle.getString( "CourseName");
    subjectName = bundle.getString( "SubjectName");
}
```

Comment: please fix your main2activity xml file

Comment: and you can use getActivity too.

Comment: onActivityCreated didn't work also , I'm not trying to bore you and I'm thankful that you and @Satan Pandeya are trying with me but I've been stuck with this error for almost a day now

Comment: you did in both fragment??

Comment: yeah both of them

Comment: Thanks for helping , This with declaring LinearLayoutManager as global worked well

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare twice `setLayoutManager()` method. You are doing:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
mSubjectsList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
mSubjectsList.setLayoutManager(mSubjectsList.getLayoutManager());
```

Instead of this, just declare:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
mSubjectsList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Try to move your `recyclerView` data from `onCreateView` to `onViewCreated`.

Inside `onCreateView()` method:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment, container, false);
}
```

Now add your `recyclerView` content to `onViewCreated()` method:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewId);

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mSubjectsList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to uncomment this , it was a try with no success , but the problem still exists . Edited

Comment: Post your onCreateView method and xml too if possible.

Comment: Edited : XML and onCreateView are added

Comment: Still the same error.
I don't know how exactly the layout manager works in fragments, Is the problem that it has been set for the first fragment in the activity ?

Comment: There is type cast problem i think. Do like this:  RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewId);

Comment: you are doing :     mSubjectsList = view.findViewById(R.id.subjects_rv);
 Here is missing (RecyclerView).

Comment: It's says "Casting is redundant"
anyway i tried with no success either

Comment: Thanks for helping , This with the help of jigar savaliya with declaring LinearLayoutManager as global worked well